# Passing data to Ajax Error block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a controller with the following catch statement which returns a partial view and the error to display.

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return PartialView("ErrorPartial", new ErrorModel(ex));
        }
```

This controller is being invoked through an Ajax call like this...

```
    $('#myID').ajaxSubmit({
        url: buildUrl('MyController'),
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            toggleOverlay(true, 'Saving...');
        },
        success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr) {
            successSave(responseText, statusText, xhr)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

If the exception is caught, then the code falls into the error block however I'm unable to pass the partial view data into this.

Is there anyway I can pass the partial data into the error block? If not, could you possibly recommend an alternative?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `jqXHR.responseText`. However, it's not very clear for me why does your js code fail into the error block - you've handled the exception so ajax request should be considered as successfull and success function should be triggered. Here's my C# code which leads to ajax request fail but passes the data along with the error.

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return PartialView("SomePartialView", model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up doing Response.StatusCode = 500; which is similar to your suggestion.